# base64_decode problem

Tags: php

If i decode base64 encoded bitmap, i get back nothing. Where as i should get some binary data.

Suppose $data contains base64 encoded bitmap.

```
$decoded = base64_decode($data);
```

if i echo $decoded it prints nothing even its length is '0'. Shouldnt it contain something after decoding?

Also can you decode base64 encoded binary data in php?

Comment: Yes, it should contain something. Make sure that $data is *only* base64-encoded data, nothing else.

Comment: if you look at your PHP errors, you should find that $data is not valid base64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it wrong, even when api said it was encypted data it wasn't encrypted.